# Gas stove burner won't shut off

Tags: valve, stove, natural-gas

I have a very old Viking Professional range in my house. The former owner told us that the front right burner wouldn't shut off one day and he was forced to adjust a screw within the knob post in order to get it off. I haven't personally played with it as I don't want to risk a gas leak.

**Questions:**

- Does anyone know if there is normally some kind of a "set screw" on gas burner assemblies?
- Does this seem like a calibration issue or something deeper?
- Does Viking build their burners differently than most stove manufacturers?

  - I've not worked extensively with stoves, but I'm curious if concepts from other stoves could be applied.

**Notes**

- The oven is a Viking Professional VGRC485-4GQDPL
- It is a natural gas oven.
- Here is [a link to the full parts list](http://authorizedvikingparts.com/media/wysiwyg/VGRC485.pdf) for my model
- I believe [this is the part in question](http://www.allvikingparts.com/003515_000_Valve_and_Bolt_Sub_From_PA010024_003519_p/003515-000.htm) - PA010024 VALVE AND BOLT KIT

  - [image: 003515-000 replaces 003519-000]
  - Apparently 003515-000 replaces 003519-000 - 003515-000 depicted above.
  - The protruding piece from the part (at the top) is the post that the knob attaches to.

Hoping that someone can help keep me from blowing myself up! :D

Comment: TL;DR. Futzing with broken gas hardware is not the name of the game. Buy that part and put it in. YouTube: [Burner Valve Replacement on a Pre 2010 Lacanche Range](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OI6IMVFjN-Q)

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense and the part isn't too expensive - I don't think it's worth the risk either. Thanks a lot for the link! My Viking is probably quite similar to that range.